# Play 2.1 framework not detecting evolution changes

Tags: playframework-2.0, ebean, playframework-evolutions

On adding a @ManyToMany join table to two models, in this case User and Article models[1], Play correctly detects these changes and modifies the 1.sql[2] file accordingly:

```
[1]
+    @ManyToMany
+    public List<User> authors;

+    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="authors")
+    public List<Article> authoredArticles;

[2]
+    create table articles_users (
+      articles_id                    bigint not null,
+      users_id                       bigint not null,
+      constraint pk_articles_users primary key (articles_id, users_id)
+    );

+    alter table articles_users add constraint fk_articles_users_articles_01 foreign key (articles_id) references articles (id);
+    alter table articles_users add constraint fk_articles_users_users_02 foreign key (users_id) references users (id);

# --- !Downs

+    drop table if exists articles_users cascade;
```

However when opening a page that uses this relationship, no message is displayed about Evolutions needing applying, instead the following error is presented:

```
PersistenceException: Query threw SQLException:ERROR: relation "articles_users" does not exist
```

Why is Play not detecting that it has made changes to the database schema that need to be applied?

Comment: Have you this problem in production or development environment?

Comment: Development, the app is not currently in production.

Answer (score 2):

Check the play_evolutions table, if there is already a row with id 1 you have to rename the sql file to 2.sql or drop the tables manually.